# Sitefinity 4 Products module Example doesn't create custom widget template

Tags: custom-controls, sitefinity-4

We are trying to use the Sitefinity 4 Products module that comes as an example in their SDK as a foundation for a couple custom content types we are creating.

When we use Products module example, we can see it created 2 new entries under the widget template to create custom widget templates. However, when we try to create the template, it will not show up in the list of available widget templates.

What is missing that is preventing the widget template we are creating from showing up on the list for editing. The widget template we create doesn't show up under All Templates nor my Templates.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue before, it turned out that my templates were set with a Build Action of "Content" instead of "Embedded Resource".

hope this is helpful!

Comment: Thanks for you response. I double checked the properties of the files. They are all set as embedded content types. Upon further investigation, we noticed that there is a field (area_name) in the sf_presentation_data table that is not being populated. When we type in a value here, it will show up in the widget template list. We double check the code and it should be receiving a value. We are still looking as to why this value is not being passed through when a widget template is created.

Answer (score 0):

I received a response from Telerik, it is a bug in their system that the widget module does not pick up the area name from custom modules. This should be fixed in a future release of Sitefinity. In the mean time, you can update the record in the sf_presentation_data table to contain an area_name so it will show up as an option in the admin.